# Surface integral for a scalar function defined on a discrete surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, integration, curvature, discrete-geometry

Imagine a polyhedral, discrete surface embedded in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Its faces are all triangles. For each vertex, one can compute the discrete mean and Gaussian curvatures and evaluate the sum of square principal curvatures, $k_1^2 + k_2^2$.

The goal is to evaluate the bending energy at a vertex $v_0$ by computing this integral over all incident triangles at the $v_0$ vertex:

$$ \int_{S}{k_1^2+k_2^2 dS} $$

The problem is that there's no analytical expression for the $k_i$ curvatures, they're just scalars associated to each $v_k$ vertex of the mesh.

Is there a way to evaluate this particular surface integral? Or, more clearly, given a random triangle in 3D with scalars attached to its vertices, can a notion of surface integral for a function that just interpolates the scalar values over this triangle be established in a consistent way? (then I can just sum the integrals over all triangles and get a numerical estimate).

*NOTE*

The purpose of computing that surface integral is to assess the importance of a vertex as a salient feature in a local context for a polyhedral surface. The entire concept should be implementable using a computer programming language (hence the more abstract mathematical quirks and impediments may be overlooked up to an acceptable limit).

For a "quick" reference, a good survey of how some continuous differential geometry concepts are adapted in the discrete context, you can consult CalTech's Graphics Group tech report on the issue: http://multires.caltech.edu/pubs/diffGeoOps.pdf

**Solution proposition**

Let $f(v) = (k_1^2 + k_2^2)(v)$ be a positive scalar function defined on the polyhedral surface. Evaluating $\int_S{f dS}$ can be done by summing all $\int_{\Delta{ijk}}{f dS}$ over all $(v_i,v_j,v_k)$ triangular faces of the surface. Then the problem is reduced to evaluating:

$$ \int_{\Delta{ijk}}{f dS} = \int_s \int_t { f(v(s,t)) \left| \frac{\partial v}{\partial s} \times \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\right| ds dt },$$
where $v(s,t)$ is a parameterization for the $\Delta_{ijk}$ triangle. For example,
$v(s,t) = (1-t)((1-s)v_1 + sv_2) + tv_3$, where $(s,t) \in [0,1]^2$.

Now, we require that $f(v(0,0))=f(v_1)=K_1$, $f(v(1,0))=f(v_2)=K_2$ and $f(v(0,1))=f(v_3)=K_3$, i.e. $f(v_i)=K_i$. Hence $f$ can also be a convex combination of $K_1$, $K_2$ and $K_3$, but this time over a triangular domain that is isometric to $\Delta_{v_1v_2v_3}$. 
[image]
There should exist a parameterization $v^*(s,t)$ of the $\Delta_{v_1v_2v_3}$ triangle such that $\left| \frac{\partial v}{\partial s} \times \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}\right| = 1$ (`is this affirmation valid?`).

Since the image of $f(\Delta_{v_1v_2v_3})$ is also a triangle (it is a convex combination of $K_i$s), and since there must be a "canonical" parameterization $v^*(s,t)$ of $\Delta$, then we can compute the resulting double integral as the volume under the $K_1K_2K_3$ triangle over the triangular domain that is isometric to $\Delta_{v_1v_2v_3}$. This solid object is a generalized triangular prism (its base planes are not necessarily parallel anymore).

*Is there any obvious flaw in the above solution?*

Comment: This is just a simple impression after reading your question. If you use very simple approximations of curvature you can always achieve an $o(d)$-precision, where $d$ is the maximum diameter of your triangles. But if you want to achieve higher precision, you'll need to do tricky approximations, involving more information of surface geometry. Simple approximations are any from instruments that are usually used for that: linear approximations, splines, etc.

Comment: Actually, any kind of approximation would be good for starters as precision isn't the biggest problem. I wonder if I could consider each triangle to lie in the XOY plane and define a function $f$ over this triangle. $f$ should interpolate the curvature values at the triangle's vertices. Then computing the area under the triangle $(x,y, f(x,y))$ could be the answer, but I have a feeling this is alchemy.

Comment: Are you sure that principal curvatures are associated only to vertices? Defining them on edges would make a lot of sense, one of them would be zero of course (for each edge).

Comment: You can associate them to any point on the polyhedral surface, but if you want to qualitatively asses the importance of a vertex, then you must see what happens in the vicinity of that vertex, i.e. all neighbouring 1-ring incident triangles to it.

Comment: @studiosus One thing that confuses me here is that set of non-zero values of $k_1^2 + k_2^2$ for true polyhedra has zero measure (edges and vertices). Am I missing something?

Comment: @Evgeny: That's not a problem, think of curvature as a signed measure singular with respect to Lebesgue. This works nicely for the intrinsic geometry and Gaussian curvature.

Comment: @studiosus But doesn't it yield that integral will be zero?

Comment: Teodron: Ok, so what do you assign to the edges?

Comment: @studiosus: for an edge, you could always LERP the $k_1^2+k_2^2$ values of its endpoints. The same goes for a point on a triangular face: interpolate its value from the vertices.

Comment: @Evgeny, if you compute the surface integral of a function over something that lacks the dimension of a surface element, I guess common sense (not only measure theory) tells us that the integral is zero.. but this is discrete differential geometry, and the issue is adapting a continuous concept as faithfully to the discrete context. I'm not looking for abstract caveats coming from Measure Theory because, well, I will have to use a computer to perform practical calculations and measurements. I can't just "measure" abstract sets using digital tools :(..

Comment: I'll edit the question to reflect the need of adapting a continuous concept to a discrete context

Comment: @teodron I understand your needs since I'm close enough to programming :) my questions about zero measure set were intended to establish the fact (in first order for myself) that approximating surface with planar triangular patches isn't suitable for bending energy computation — it's always zero w.r.t. to Lebesgue integration (and it's reasonable, since piecewise-linear surface is almost nowhere bended).

Comment: @Evgeny, I agree with your observation, my bad for not clarifying. the scenario. you should consider each point to have a convex combination of the energies stored. at the vertices of the triangle it lies in.

Comment: @Evgeny: No, just think of a measure concentrated in a finite number if atoms. The integral reduces to a finite sum over the atoms: Just forget the Lebesgue measure, it becomes irrelevant!

Comment: @teodron Assumptions and idea in this setting seems legit for me

Comment: I think the treatment is in *finite difference equations* and their numerical approximations.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this looks like an open ended discussion that started more than ten years ago and ended eight years ago.

Answer (score 0):

The flaw is not that obvious but if you expand one term of the cross operation you will find that the the cross product is independent of the parameter *s*. The reason for this is that $(1-t)((1-s)v_1+sv_2)+tv_3$ is a good way to describe scalar function on the triangle but a wrong way to describe the area. In other words, the parameters $s$ and $t$ are not orthogonal.

Comment: The $\frac{\partial v}{\partial s} \times \frac{\partial v}{\partial t}$ is an expression involving both $s$ and $t$. Are you certain about the $s$ terms being null? I did not understand what you meant when described the scalar parameters $s$ and $t$ as "not orthogonal". Could you also expand on what you meant by "a good way to describe a scalar function" (actually that is a vector valued function) and "a wrong way to describe area" (the area is usually proportional to the norm of the cross product of the sides of a triangle).